# Hardcoded Input field is not send in Django Form

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a simple question I hope. I hardcoded a input field in between `<form>` and `</form>` in my page. I am using [bootstrap toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/):

```
<input class="form-control" id="dividend-yield-enabled" name="dividend-yield-enabled"
    data-size="mini" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled"
    type="checkbox" data-onstyle="default"
    {% if suggestion.dividend_yield_influence != 0 %}checked{% endif %}/>
```

but I can not see this field in views.py file. I am printing POST request directly:  `print request.POST` and I can not see above mentioned field. There are all other input fields, but this Bootstrap Toogle is missing. What am I missing? Why is it not sent along with other form fields?

---

**EDIT1:**
Here is my view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def screener(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST
```

and here is my [html](http://pastebin.com/KFvrQEh7).
I am missing `dividend-yield-enabled` in `request.POST`, This is what I see now:

```
<QueryDict: {u'payout-ratio-influence': [u'3'], u'dgr5-influence': [u'1'], u'dividend-yield': [u'0,5'], u'payout-ratio': [u'0,60'], u'dgr3-influence': [u'1'], u'lists': [u'5', u'6', u'7'], u'dgr5': [u'0,20'], u'dividend-yield-influence': [u'5'], u'dgr3': [u'0,20'], u'category-influence': [u'1'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'5bEpa2lkmW2qiOnPZtEkHQIkyKYRbVL6']}>
```

Comment: Please show us your views.py. Also show the whole form html.

Comment: @ShangWang Hi, added as **EDIT1**.

Comment: I'm quite sure that it's not about django because it does not filter POST data in any way. Can you debug with your browser to be sure that data is sent to the server?

Comment: How do I check sent form data in browser? Well, I found my problem. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was the problem. It could have crossed my mind earlier, that I was using untested/old middleware. I used [Strip Whitespace Middleware](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/StripWhitespaceMiddleware), because my templates were generating too many blank lines. After uncommenting that middleware `u'dividend-yield-enabled': [u'on']` appeared in form data. Thanks again for comments.